# palindrome words program in php

Tags: php, palindrome

there is a String 'S', program is to find and print whether this string is a palindrome or not. If yes, print "YES", else print "NO"

for some palindrome words it is working like civic and for some it is not working
code:-

```
<?php
$str = "Civic";

$count =  ((strlen($str)+1 ) /2);
$q = "y";
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{   
    $x = 1;
    $z = $str[(strlen($str-$x))];
    $x = $x+1;
    if($str[$i] == $z ) {
        $x = $x++;
        $q = "y";
    } else {
        $q = "n";  
    }
}
if($q == "n") {
    echo "No";
} else {
    echo "Yes";
}   
?>
```

Please give me some suggestions about my code, Thanks

Comment: Here's one suggestion: fix that crazy indentation. :p

Comment: *"and for some it is not working"* - as in which word(s)?

Comment: That's a lot of effort for what should be a simple two-liner (assuming ASCII)

Comment: "and for some it is not working" are Racecar,Mom,aba

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a different approach:

```
if($str == strrev($str)) {
    echo "Yes";
} else {
    echo "No";
}
```

Or shorter:

```
echo ($str == strrev($str)) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

But maybe the problem is case sensitivity?

```
echo (strtolower($str) == strrev(strtolower($str))) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Comment: Brilliant! Bravo! (The best solutions are often the simplest.)

Comment: Let's only hope there isn't a rabbit hole around that (question) ;-)

Comment: [You know I put in a good word for you...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378656/palindrome-words-program-in-php#comment71906780_42378656) ;-)

Comment: Thank you every one specially AbraCadaver!